# How can I use a single port of PIC18F4550 as both input and output

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip

I'm trying to use port B of PIC18F4550 as both inputs and outputs. What I need to do is to connect a 7-segment-display and also connect 4 push buttons to the same port, this means that I need to use the same port as inputs and outputs and it's supossed that when the I introduce the number from 0 to 15 (F) then the port B must recognize this inputs and then start to work as outputs and send a '1' to the respective pines of the 7-segment-display in order to see corresponding number in decimal.
My code is the following one and I'm using **PIC C Compiler**:

```
#include<18F4550.h>
#fuses XT, NOPROTECT, NOWDT, NOLVP, PUT
#use delay(clock = 4M, crystal = 8M)
#use fast_io(b)

int DSPIN;
int DSPOUT = 0;
int DSPVALOR[16] = {                  
                 0b00111111,//0
                 0b00000110,//1
                 0b01011011,//2
                 0b01001111,//3
                 0b01100110,//4
                 0b01101101,//5
                 0b01111101,//6
                 0b01000111,//7
                 0b01111111,//8
                 0b01100111,//9
                 0b01110111,//A
                 0b01111100,//b
                 0b00111001,//C
                 0b01011110,//d
                 0b01111001,//E
                 0b01110001 //F
             };
void main(){

 SET_TRIS_B(0b00001111);
 DSPIN = input_b();

 while(true){
  
  if(DSPIN == 0b00000000){
     DSPOUT = 0;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000001){
     DSPOUT = 1;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000010){
     DSPOUT = 2;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000011){
     DSPOUT = 3;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000100){
     DSPOUT = 4;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000101){
     DSPOUT = 5;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000110){
     DSPOUT = 6;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00000111){
     DSPOUT = 7;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001000){
     DSPOUT = 8;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001001){
     DSPOUT = 9;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001010){
     DSPOUT = 10;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001011){
     DSPOUT = 11;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001100){
     DSPOUT = 12;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001101){
     DSPOUT = 13;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001110){
     DSPOUT = 14;
  }
  else if(DSPIN == 0b00001111){
     DSPOUT = 15;
  }
  else{
     DSPOUT = 0;
  }
  
  delay_ms(1000);
  SET_TRIS_B(0b11111111);
  
  switch(DSPOUT){
     
     case 0:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[0]);
     break;
     
     case 1:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[1]);
     break;
     
     case 2:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[2]);
     break;
     
     case 3:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[3]);
     break;
     
     case 4:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[4]);
     break;
     
     case 5:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[5]);
     break;
     
     case 6:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[6]);
     break;
     
     case 7:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[7]);
     break;
     
     case 8:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[8]);
     break;
     
     case 9:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[9]);
     break;
     
     case 10:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[10]);
     break;
     
     case 11:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[11]);
     break;
     
     case 12:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[12]);
     break;
     
     case 13:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[13]);
     break;
     
     case 14:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[14]);
     break;
     
     case 15:
        output_b(DSPVALOR[15]);
     break;
     
     Default: 
        output_b(DSPVALOR[0]);
     break;
  }
     delay_ms(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not thinking clearly about your code ... you have multiples of code like `if(DSPIN == 0b00000110){ DSPOUT = 6; }` .... it is same as `if(DSPIN == 6){  DSPOUT = 6; }` .... do you see a simpler way of writing the code?

Comment: lol .... `if (DSPIN < 16) {DSPOUT = DSPIN;} else {DSPOUT = 0;}`

Comment: and instead of the switch: `output_b(DSPVALOR[DSPOUT];`

Comment: Do you score points for more lines of code?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on two sites at the same time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143165/how-can-i-create-a-bidirectional-bus-using-a-18f4550

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it was my first time posting here. I've already updated in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143165/how-can-i-create-a-bidirectional-bus-using-a-18f4550 I've corrected the code and also provided the connection diagram so if you all want to take a look over there.